# GenServer's code_change got invoked again even if vsn is fixed to last version in successive hot code upgrade?

Tags: elixir

The second upgrade release cannot be installed successfully. From the error log below, seems the code_change function is invoked again and processed the state incorrectly.

**Steps to reproduce**

I am following the examples and steps in book "Programming Elixir >= 1.6" chapter 20 OTP.Applications.

- On commit [one](https://github.com/kenspirit/programming-elixir-exercises/commit/3df90c00690fe72894a8c82034d0a3a381a536cd), I have prepared the application as 0.2.0 version
- On commit [two](https://github.com/kenspirit/programming-elixir-exercises/commit/f3801929d9ff2f38615a21438e5177167c82a527), the state in `server.ex` has been updated and need to run code_change. I can hot upgrade the code to 0.3.0 successfully.

After above two steps, if I simply change the return text in `next_number` function in `server.ex` and upgrade the version to 0.3.1 for example, leaving the code_change function in step 2 untouched, the hot upgrade will fail with below error.

After step 2, I did run new function `Sequence.Server.next_number()` and `Sequence.Server.increment_number(2)` several times to make sure it takes effect and the state is updated to new format.

The question is that why the `code_change("0")` with version marked as the last version can still be triggered in the second upgrade?

**Error Logs**

> Release handler failed to install: {:code_change_failed,
>
> ## PID<10063.770.0>, Sequence.Server, "1", {:EXIT, {:function_clause, [{Sequence.Server, :code_change, ["1", %{**struct**:
>
> Sequence.Server.State, current_number: 8, delta: 2}, []], [file:
> 'lib/sequence/server.ex', line: 44]}, {:gen_server,
> :system_code_change, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 794]}, {:sys,
> :do_change_code, 5, [file: 'sys.erl', line: 573]}, {:sys, :do_cmd, 6,
> [file: 'sys.erl', line: 465]}, {:sys, :handle_system_msg, 8, [file:
> 'sys.erl', line: 365]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file:
> 'proc_lib.erl', line: 249]}]}}}

**Description of issue**

What are the expected results? hot code upgrade should be successful
What version of Distillery? 2.0.9
What OS, Erlang/Elixir versions are you seeing this issue on? Mac 10.13.6, Elixir 1.7.2

This question is actually asked as an [issue](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/issues/523) of distillery in Github also.

Answer (score 1):

The call fails as it attempts to call your `code_change` function with `"1"` as the first parameter - read the error message. It starts with the submitted parameters. Your current code only allows you (the BEAM, etc) to call the `code_change/3` function with "0" as the first parameter. Any other case is not matched / allowed.

If you were to add another matching clause for your code_change function you can ignore / handle the version change to `"1"`:

```
def code_change("0", old_state = current_number, _extra) do
  new_state = %State{
    current_number: current_number,
    delta: 1
  }
  IO.puts inspect old_state
  IO.puts inspect new_state
  { :ok, new_state }
end
def code_change("1", state, _extra) do
  # your code here for version "1"
  {:ok, state}
end
def code_change(_version, state, _extra) do
  # your code here for any other version
  {:ok, state}
end
```